# Transparent background for android

Tags: java, android, background

i want to make my own background transparent, can anyone guide me how. 
below is the background color i wanna use and i want it transparent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#000000"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:background="@null" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#C0C0C0" android:centerColor="#C0C0C0"  android:endColor="#C0C0C0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Have you tried android:background="@android:color/transparent". Its a bad idea of using android:background="@null")?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@android:color/transparent` for your background field, it is the android's system color for transparency